# Creating a function for my python web scraper that will output a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, function, dictionary, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have created my web **scraper** I have added an function unfortunately my function is not calling the out put is not coming out as a dictionary. How do I create and call the function and store the output as a dictionary. Below is my code and function so far.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


top_stories = []

def get_stories():


    """ user agent to facilitates end-user interaction with web content"""

    headers = {
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.101 Safari/537.36'
    }



    base_url = 'www.example.com'

    source = requests.get(base_url).text
    

    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
    
    articles = soup.find_all("article", class_="card")
    print(f"Number of articles found: {len(articles)}")

    for article in articles:
        try:
            headline = article.h3.text.strip()
            link = base_url + article.a['href']
            text = article.find("div", class_="field--type-text-with-summary").text.strip()
            img_url = base_url + article.picture.img['data-src']
        
            print(headline,link,text,img_url)
        
        
            stories_dict = {}
            stories_dict['Headline'] = headline
            stories_dict['Link'] = link
            stories_dict['Text'] = text
            stories_dict['Image'] = img_url
        
            top_stories.append(stories_dict)
        
        except AttributeError as ex:
            print('Error:',ex)
        
get stories()
```

Comment: Please share the link to the page you are scraping

Comment: **https://www.jse.co.za**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the data in a dictionary format (`dict`), you can create a dictionary as follows:

```
top_stories = {"Headline": [], "Link": [], "Text": [], "Image": []}
```

and append the correct data to it.

(by the way, when you have specified your `headers`, it should have been a `dict` not a `set`.)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def get_stories():
    """user agent to facilitates end-user interaction with web content"""

    headers = {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.101 Safari/537.36"
    }

    top_stories = {"Headline": [], "Link": [], "Text": [], "Image": []}
    base_url = "https://www.jse.co.za/"

    source = requests.get(base_url, headers=headers).text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")

    articles = soup.find_all("article", class_="card")
    print(f"Number of articles found: {len(articles)}")

    for article in articles:
        try:
            top_stories["Headline"].append(article.h3.text.strip())
            top_stories["Link"].append(base_url + article.a["href"])
            top_stories["Text"].append(
                article.find("div", class_="field--type-text-with-summary").text.strip()
            )
            top_stories["Image"].append(base_url + article.picture.img["data-src"])

        except AttributeError as ex:
            print("Error:", ex)

    print(type(top_stories))
    print(top_stories)


get_stories()
```

Output:

```
Number of articles found: 6
<class 'dict'>
{'Headline': ['South Africa offers investment opportunities to Asia Pacific investors', 'South Africa to showcase investment opportunities to the UAE market', 'South Africa to showcase investment opportunities to UK investors', 'JSE to become 100% owner of JSE Investor Services and expands services to include share plan administration services', 'Thungela Resources lists on the JSE after unbundling from Anglo American', 'JSE welcomes SAB’s B-BBEE scheme that gives investors exposure to AB InBev global market'], 'Link': ['https://www.jse.co.za//news/market-news/south-africa-offers-investment-opportunities-asia-pacific-investors', 'https://www.jse.co.za//news/market-news/south-africa-showcase-investment-opportunities-uae-market', 'https://www.jse.co.za//news/market-news/south-africa-showcase-investment-opportunities-uk-investors', 'https://www.jse.co.za//news/market-news/jse-become-100-owner-jse-investor-services-and-expands-services-include-share-plan', 'https://www.jse.co.za//news/market-news/thungela-resources-lists-jse-after-unbundling-anglo-american', 'https://www.jse.co.za//news/market-news/jse-welcomes-sabs-b-bbee-scheme-gives-investors-exposure-ab-inbev-global-market'], 'Text': ['The Johannesburg Stock Exchange (JSE) and joint sponsors, Citi and Absa Bank are collaborating to host the annual SA Tomorrow Investor conference, which aims to showcase the country’s array of investment opportunities to investors in the Asia Pacific region, mainly from Hong Kong and Singapore.', 'The Johannesburg Stock Exchange (JSE) and joint sponsors, Citi and Absa Bank are collaborating to host the SA Tomorrow Investor conference, which aims to position South Africa as a preferred investment destination for the United Arab Emirates (UAE) market.', 'The Johannesburg Stock Exchange (JSE) and joint sponsors Citi and Absa Bank are collaborating to host the annual SA Tomorrow Investor conference, which aims to showcase the country’s array of investment opportunities to investors in the United Kingdom.', 'The Johannesburg Stock Exchange (JSE) is pleased to announce that it has embarked on a process to incorporate JSE Investor Services Proprietary Limited (JIS) as a wholly owned subsidiary of the JSE by acquiring the minority shareholding of 25.15 % from LMS Partner Holdings.', 'Shares in Thungela Resources, a South African thermal coal exporter, today commenced trading on the commodity counter of the Main Board of the Johannesburg Stock Exchange (JSE).', 'From today, Black South African retail investors will get the opportunity to invest in the world’s largest beer producer, AB InBev, following the listing of SAB Zenzele Kabili on the Johannesburg Stock Exchange’s (JSE) Empowerment Segment.'], 'Image': ['https://www.jse.co.za//sites/default/files/styles/standard_lg/public/medial/images/2021-06/Web_Banner_0.jpg?h=4ae650de&itok=hdGEy5jA', 'https://www.jse.co.za//sites/default/files/styles/standard_lg/public/medial/images/2021-06/Web_Banner2.jpg?h=4ae650de&itok=DgPFtAx8', 'https://www.jse.co.za//sites/default/files/styles/standard_lg/public/medial/images/2021-06/Web_Banner.jpg?h=4ae650de&itok=Q0SsPtAz', 'https://www.jse.co.za//sites/default/files/styles/standard_lg/public/medial/images/2020-12/DSC_0832.jpg?h=156fdada&itok=rL3M2gpn', 'https://www.jse.co.za//sites/default/files/styles/standard_lg/public/medial/images/2021-06/Thungela_Web_Banner_1440x390.jpg?h=4ae650de&itok=kKRO5fQk', 'https://www.jse.co.za//sites/default/files/styles/standard_lg/public/medial/images/2021-05/SAB-Zenzele.jpg?h=4ae650de&itok=n9osAP33']}
```

Comment: In `source = requests.get(base_url, headers=headers).text` I was getting error message whenever I added `headers=headers`

Comment: @coja56 Yeah, that's why I added in my answer that `headers` should be a dictionary. See how I have defined it in my answer